# Unexpected behavior in FIRST_VALUE() with IGNORE NULLS (Vertica)

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm seeing unexpected behavior in Vertica's FIRST_VALUE() analytic function with the IGNORE NULLS parameter. It appears to return NULL when it shouldn't.

The issue occurs in this very tiny table:

```
drop table if exists temp;
create table temp (time_ timestamp(6), name varchar(10));
insert into temp (time_) values ('2016-03-18 20:32:16.144');
insert into temp (time_, name) values ('2016-03-18 20:52:09.062', 'abc');
```

Here are the contents of the table (select * from temp):

```
time_                   | name
------------------------+--------
2016-03-18 20:32:16.144 | <null>
2016-03-18 20:52:09.062 | abc
```

Here is the query I'm running:

```
select time_,
  first_value(name ignore nulls) over (order by time_) first_name
from temp;
```

Here are the results this query returns:

```
time_                   | first_name
------------------------+------------
2016-03-18 20:32:16.144 | <null>
2016-03-18 20:52:09.062 | abc
```

Here are the results I would expect (and desire) from this query:

```
time_                   | first_name
------------------------+------------
2016-03-18 20:32:16.144 | abc
2016-03-18 20:52:09.062 | abc
```

Does the above query have a very fundamental syntax mistake? This issue occurs on Vertica Community Edition 7.1.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function works as expected.
`over (order by time_)` is a shortcut for `over (order by time_ range unbounded preceding)` which is a shortcut for `over (order by time_ range between unbounded preceding and current row)`, which means every row sees only the rows that preceded it, including itself.
The first row sees only itself therefore there isn't a non NULL value in its scope.

If you want the first non NULL value of the whole scope, you have to specify the whole scope:

```
first_value(name ignore nulls) over 
    (order by time_ range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) first_name
```

---

No, this is definitly not a bug.

You've probably have been using syntax like `sum(x) over (order by y)` for running totals and the default window of RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING seemed very natural to you.
Since you had not define an explicit window for the FIRST_VALUE function, you have been using the same default window.

Here is another test case:

```
ts val
-- ----
1  NULL
2  X
3  NULL
4  Y
5  NULL
```

What would you expect to get from the following function?

```
last_value (val) order (by ts)
```

What would you expect to get from the following function?

```
last_value (val ignore nulls) order (by ts)
```

Comment: Very interesting. Seems more like a bug than a feature to me, but glad to know the full story. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the additional examples! Super helpful.

Answer (score 5):

This is where my thinking takes me

```
select time_
      ,first_value(name) over (order by case when name is null then 1 else 0 end,time_) FirstName
from temp A
order by time_
```

Returns

```
time_               FirstName
20:32:16.1440000    abc
20:52:09.0620000    abc
```

Comment: Thanks for this workaround. (In Vertica CE 7.1.1 this exact syntax doesn't work, but you can do: `select time_, first_value(name) over (order by case when name is null then 1 else 0 end, time_) first_name from temp`). But shouldn't IGNORE NULLS do this exact thing?

Comment: @verbatross Happy you were able to adjust.   Shocked that it doesn't support IIF()

Comment: @verbatross searching... but so far I only see ignore nulls in AWS

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, Oracle, Teradata, MySql, PostgreSQL, SQLite are just some of the database that do not support the non-standard IIF which supply a functionality that is already covered by the CASE statement which is a standard . It would be more of a shock to find someone that do support it. P.s. Oracle and Teradata support IGNORE NULLS

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I saw that afterwards...  I saw SQL and went on auto pilot.