# MySQL SELECT with LEFT JOIN unexpectedly inserts NULLs into first row of each partition

Tags: mysql, null, left-join

I have two tables. One with stock prices and one with share numbers for each stock. I want to join the two tables and calculate a market cap for each stock.

Here is a sample data table with just 3 stocks I have created to replicate the problem.

```
CREATE TABLE stock_prices (country_exchange_code VARCHAR(2), stock_code VARCHAR(4), date DATE, close FLOAT, PRIMARY KEY (country_exchange_code,stock_code,date));

INSERT INTO stock_prices VALUES
    ("T", "1301",   '2019-10-29',   75.2),
    ("T", "1301",   '2019-10-30',   76.6),
    ("T", "1301",   '2019-10-31',   77.6),
    ("T", "1301",   '2019-11-01',   77.2),
    ("T", "1332",   '2019-10-29',   52.5),
    ("T", "1332",   '2019-10-30',   49.7),
    ("T", "1332",   '2019-10-31',   50.8),
    ("T", "1332",   '2019-11-01',   50.4),
    ("T", "1333",   '2019-10-29',   13.9),
    ("T", "1333",   '2019-10-30',   13.8),
    ("T", "1333",   '2019-10-31',   14.3),
    ("T", "1333",   '2019-11-01',   14.4);

CREATE TABLE stock_shares (country_exchange_code VARCHAR(2), stock_code VARCHAR(4), Num_Shares INT, PRIMARY KEY (country_exchange_code,stock_code));    

INSERT INTO stock_shares VALUES
    ("T", "1301",   241587962),
    ("T", "1332",   369875187),
    ("T", "1333",   958621587);
```

The following query joins the two tables on the country code, and stock code and then lists the number of shares and the last closing price which are the inputs into the calculated Market Cap value. I use the last_value window function to get the last closing price.

```
SELECT Stock_Code, Date, Num_Shares, 
        last_value(Close) OVER (PARTITION BY Stock_Code ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS Last_Close,
        Num_Shares * last_value(Close) OVER (PARTITION BY Stock_Code ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS Mkt_Cap
    FROM stock_prices LEFT JOIN stock_shares USING (Country_Exchange_Code, Stock_Code)
    WHERE Country_Exchange_Code = 'T' AND Date >= '2019-10-29' 
    ORDER BY Stock_Code, Date;
```

This works as expected and produces the following result:

Result 1:

[image: Result 1]

Next I want to use DISTINCT statement to arrive at just one row for each stock. However I first need to get rid of all the columns except Stock_Code and Mkt_Cap. This is where the problem occurs. When I eliminate the Last_Close column from the select statement:

```
SELECT Stock_Code, Date, Num_Shares, 

        Num_Shares * last_value(Close) OVER (PARTITION BY Stock_Code ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS Mkt_Cap
    FROM stock_prices LEFT JOIN stock_shares USING (Country_Exchange_Code, Stock_Code)
    WHERE Country_Exchange_Code = 'T' AND Date >= '2019-10-29' 
    ORDER BY Stock_Code, Date;
```

I get these unexpected NULLs popping up in the first row of each stock code partition.

Result 2:

[image: Result 2]

Why is this happening? There are no NULLs in my tables and as we saw from the first result, all the data required to calculate Mkt_Cap is there.

Extra Information:
When I remove Date and/or Num_Shares from the SELECT statement there is no problem. It is only the removal of the last_value function that causes the problem.

Interestingly, when the WHERE clause is removed the problem goes away. I can't understand how this effects the result because in my small sample this WHERE clause doesn't even do anything. All my data have Country_Exchange_Code = 'T' and have Date >= '2019-10-29'. But in my actual data set with millions of rows this WHERE clause is highly necessary. So removing the WHERE clause is not a solution.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: This appears to be a bug. (If you replace the (PARTITION ...)s by w & add WINDOW w (PARTITION ...) then you get nulls in the case with both columns.)

Comment: @philipxy If not using an image of the result, how would you post such a table showing all the column headers and NULLs etc? I didn't see any way to do it in the SO editor.

Comment: Cut & paste the text from your gui. Or free OCR is online. There are also free sites online to format tables from code/CSVs. Or cut & paste from a sql fiddle output. You ought to prepare one & give (in addition to all relevant i/o & code as text) a link as part of the obligatory [mre], see the link in one of the answers. Preferably SO-supported sqlfiddle.com but they don't have many versions of DBMSs. Format as a code block, see edit help & some questions tagged sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see, what you can else Do, i think it is still a bug.
To circumvent it:

```
SELECT
  Stock_Code, `Date`, Num_Shares, (Num_Shares * Mkt_Cap) Mkt_Cap
FROM
(SELECT Stock_Code, Date, Num_Shares, Close,

         (last_value(Close) OVER (PARTITION BY Stock_Code
         ORDER BY `Date` 
         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)) AS Mkt_Cap
    FROM stock_prices3 LEFT JOIN stock_shares3 USING (Country_Exchange_Code, Stock_Code)
    WHERE Country_Exchange_Code = 'T' AND Date >= '2019-10-29' 
    ) t1
 ORDER BY Stock_Code, `Date`;
```

Like seen in he last of the select at the bottom
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=43308a7caac9e804e6a65d48b3fa7490

Comment: ORDER BY in a subquery without TOP/LIMIT is a nop. Tables have no order, query results have (partial) order.

Comment: it is vice versa, a limit without order by is possible, but not recommended.  And as far as i can see there is no Limit, but i could add a order by for the outer SElECT too

Comment: I repeat, tables have no order & in a subquery order by without top/limit has no specified effect. PS When one finds oneself saying "as far as I can see" it typically means one believes one doesn't know, one should own up to it & one should find out.

Comment: @nbk That's a good workaround solution and basically what I came up with as well. But I posted the question because I thought I shouldn't need to use a subquery here. My SQL isn't doing what I would expect in this instance.

Comment: You will make a group by stock_code and decide what to do with date i would think a concat of forst and last day.

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest to use aliases on your tables. 
The example in your code where that might be important is: `WHERE Country_Exchange_Code = 'T'` because you have a Country_Exchange_Code  column in both tables. When you are done with that part I suggest you put the column Date in the back quotes. Then have a look at this documentation here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html especially this part :

> In the following function descriptions, over_clause represents the
>   OVER clause, described in Section 12.21.2, “Window Function Concepts
>   and Syntax”. Some window functions permit a null_treatment clause that
>   specifies how to handle NULL values when calculating results. This
>   clause is optional. It is part of the SQL standard, but the MySQL
>   implementation permits only RESPECT NULLS (which is also the default).
>   This means that NULL values are considered when calculating results.
>   IGNORE NULLS is parsed, but produces an error.

Also I founded this explanation here : [Unexpected behavior in FIRST_VALUE() with IGNORE NULLS (Vertica)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40662817/unexpected-behavior-in-first-value-with-ignore-nulls-vertica)
That was helpful (it is for Vertica but ...)

And check if your calculation of the Last_Close is something that you want (your query because it gives the same result for Last_Close), Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=defa3433679c69a62ed8c0d0e954a284) where I have played and maybe it will help others or you... And here is my suggestion:

```
select sp.Stock_Code
       , sp.`Date`
       , ss.Num_Shares
       , last_value(sp.Close) OVER (PARTITION BY sp.Stock_Code ORDER BY sp.`Date`) AS Last_Close
from stock_prices sp
LEFT JOIN stock_shares ss USING (Country_Exchange_Code, Stock_Code)
    WHERE ss.Country_Exchange_Code = 'T'
    AND sp.`Date` >= '2019-10-29' 
    ORDER BY ss.Stock_Code, sp.`Date`;
```

Comment: When you test the sample with only one stock_code it delivers correct data, when you leave out the multiplicand you also get no NUL value L, so it is a **clearly** a Bug. the behaviour shows also when you multiply, add or do some mathematics with  Mkt_Cap.

Comment: Well I believe it is not a bug but regular predicted behavior. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b07006b885cb7901964faa224bb9b7cf

Comment: It is deterministic as seen here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e0079463146cd36b8b978f3512f88537  but in my opinion all select should show a complete answer and no NULL Values. So it is still a bug addid or Multilplying Value should result in a Value, when the re are no NULL Value seen

Comment: @nbk & VBokšić A JOIN result has only one of each column in a USING list so dotting is unnecessary. Although one has to remember/reference the list--unless one always dots non-USING/NATURAL columns. Standard SQL actually doesn't allow dotting a USING/NATURAL column, that's MySQL-specific. Otherwise, for other columns, I would agree, always short aliases & dots.

Comment: @VBokšić your suggestion doesn't calculate the Mkt_Cap because you left out multiplying by Num_Shares. If you add this multiplication to your suggestion the NULLs appear.

Comment: @FinGeek you are correct, what I wanted to say is : Last_Close, calculation of the Last_Close not of the Mkt_Cap. Will edit.

Comment: @VBokšić the Vertica example wasn't relevant. The problem there was due to the user not specifying the full scope of the OVER clause. But I have used ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING so that is not an issue here.

Comment: @VBokšić yes the Mkt_Cap calculation is what I want (the same result for every row) because I want the Mkt_Cap calculated off the last price only. And I am going to collapse all these identical rows with the DISTINCT clause, if I can get rid of these NULLs.

Comment: @FinGeek vertica example was to explain NULL's and point of view on the results given - I believe it is a great explanation (the one on that link).

Comment: There are no nulls going into the select clause. The WHERE removes any NULLs introduced by the LEFT JOIN.